# Validate checkbox using JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, validation, checkbox

I would like some help with checkbox validation.

If you look in below picture, when user click the image, the checkbox becomes selected.

What I would want is if all checkbox are selected alert an simple message.

[image]

This is a code to select checkbox by clicking on an image.

```
        $( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#roll-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?><?php echo $cut_counter; ?>").click (function(){
         var $$ = $(this)

          if( !$$.is('.checked')){
              $$.addClass('checked');

              $('#imgCheck-<?php echo $row['id_vnr']; ?><?php echo $cut_counter; ?>').prop('checked', true);

                }
            });
    });
```

So I can select check box by clicking on an image. How I can alert message if all check box are selected. Soon user click last picture, the picture will disappear, the red tick box will appear and user should see alert message.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by getting the number of elements with the class 'checked'. If the number is 6, then you can show the alert.

Comment: Well, it can be dynamic. Not necessarily, it will be 6 always. Good to have general solution.

Comment: Yeah it could be, in which case the OP can adjust the code to what is desired. I am just giving an idea on how to solve this problem.

Comment: Hmm, you could probably add that as a comment and not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```js
var checkboxes = $('[type="checkbox"]');
checkboxes.on('change', function() {
  var checked = $('[type="checkbox"]:checked');

  console.log('all:', checkboxes.length, ' / ', 'checked:', checked.length);

  if (checkboxes.length === checked.length) {
    console.log('ALL CHECKED!');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">1
<input type="checkbox">2
<input type="checkbox">3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following javascript code:

```
$(function(){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
     totalCheckboxCount = $('input[type="checkbox"]').length;
     selectedBoxesCount = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
     if(totalCheckboxCount == selectedBoxesCount) {
       alert("All checkboxes selected!");
     }
   });
});
```